# Decorating all django admin views (1.4+)

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views, decorator, django-urls

There used to be a neat trick for Django versions prior to 1.4 to decorate all views within the admin:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/(.*)', my_decorator(lambda *args: admin.site.root(*args))),
)
```

This no longer works as root is deprecated. I have found some [alternatives](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2532/), but they seem pretty verbose compared to what I had. Is there still a hook to do this?

Comment: I use snippet for that, I forgot what is the number of the snippet. I will search for it again

Answer (score 2):

Decorate every view in a url tree

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2607/

Comment: thanks I'll check it out, I juse found a ticket regarding the deprecation [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13409)

Comment: thanks for the info, my boss will be interested about that :)