# How to apply a decorator to all views (of a module) in django

Tags: django, python-decorators

It happens a lot, when all the views in a specific module are supposed to be available only when the user is authorized, or they should all do the same checks.

How could I avoid repeating the annotations all over the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using class-based views you can create a base class/mixin for all these views which implements the desired functionality (also using [decorators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/#decorating-the-class)) and then have all the views inherit from this base view.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class BaseView(TemplateView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # do some checking here
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            # do something if anonymous user
        return super(BaseView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)


class MyView(BaseView):
    pass
```

Answer (score 8):

In your urls

```
url(r'someregexp/$', mydecorator(view.myview.dude), 'name_of_view'),
```

Comment: Actually this just moves the annotations to the controller. You would want to wrap the include statement

Comment: Yeah, absolutely but I argue this is better due to readability and maintainability. I would argue that using a middleware (as I normally advocated before because I thought they were great) shouldn't be responsible for this. It would introduce one extra layer of complexity and also interfere with views that might be exempt for your rules but logically needs to live in that particular apps views.py. But you are 100% correct in that it moves the decorator from views.py to urls.py.

Comment: I know, just pointing that out to the OP, I agree this is more explicit and transparent :-)

Comment: Yeah, I figured you would :) But I thought I should provide some arguments for my answer, I took it as constructive criticism! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could write a dispatcher, but if you have many urls for a module it would probably be more convenient to create a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) layer.

See also: [decorating-all-django-admin-views-1-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537829/decorating-all-django-admin-views-1-4)

Answer (score 1):

When many urls need to be added, better wrap the decorator inside a function and call that function.

```
from django.conf.urls import re_path
from . import views
from somewhere import decorator


def url_with_decorator(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None):
    return re_path(regex, decorator(view), kwargs, name)

urlpatterns = [
    url_with_decorator(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url_with_decorator(r'^any_thing$', views.any_view, name='index'),
    # TODO: add url here
]
```