# How to get Django LoginRequiredMiddleware to return a 401_UNAUTHORIZED code instead of 302_FOUND

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

I am writing a custom basic `LoginRequiredMiddleware` for my Django project and so far everything works as expected. I am using `process_request` because I thought I wanted the request to be checked for authentication before the view is processed.

However, this middleware fails at a test that other developers have written:

```py
self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
AssertionError: 302 != 401
```

This happens because the view is discovered even if the user is not authenticated when it should actually return a `status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED`. How can I rewrite my middleware to comply with the test and return the correct status code?

`middleware.py`

```py
import re

from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth import logout

from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


EXEMPT_URLS = [re.compile(settings.LOGIN_URL.lstrip('/'))]
if hasattr(settings, 'LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS'):
    EXEMPT_URLS += [re.compile(url) for url in settings.LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS]


class LoginRequiredMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    
    def process_request(self, request):

        assert hasattr(request, 'user')

        path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')

        url_is_exempt = any(url.match(path) for url in EXEMPT_URLS)

        if path == settings.LOGOUT_URL.lstrip('/'):
            logout(request)

        if request.user.is_authenticated and url_is_exempt:
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

        elif request.user.is_authenticated or url_is_exempt:
            return None

        else:
            return redirect(f"{settings.LOGIN_URL}?next=/{path}")
```

Comment: Perhaps instead of using a custom middleware you could simply decorate your views with `login_required`, and a custom decorator if needed to raise 401 in appropriate views?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat there are just too many views already and more coming up. The idea is to make sure that the `@login_required` is never forgotten anywhere, that's why the middleware

Comment: The problem is that your **view** is the one throwing the 401 exception. And your middleware comes before the view. The best I can think is to add these failing urls in your exempt urls and check authentication in the view itself.

Comment: Also perhaps this [answer by uan Isaza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57269888/14991864) which creates a custom function to make url patterns might be useful.

Comment: I want the middleware to intercept the request before the url/view match is discovered. So for any URL (existing or not) I want a unauthorized user to get back a 401 instead of 302 so this should all happen before the view

Answer (score 0):

The `302` stems from the `return redirect(f'{settings.LOGIN_URL}?next=/{path}')` that you're doing to the login URL in the last step. A redirect will (and should, I'm disagreeing here with the answer which suggests redirecting and sending a `401`) always yield a status code `302`. You probably want to do a `return HttpResponse('Unauthorized', status=401)` but then you loose the convenience of forwarding your users to the login URL.

Comment: I agree with you on the redirect always returning a 302, that's how the browser understands what to do. I'm just trying to find away to make the `test_not_logged_in` pass while still having the middleware redirecting to the login page when any page is attempted to be accessed without authentication

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of modifying business logic and adding exceptions just for unit test cases (which I understand are out of your reach to change) but I think the only solution is then to catch whatever URL the unit test is testing and similar to `url_is_exempt` create a `url_is_unittest` and return a `401` in that case. But this is pretty ugly.

Comment: A different non-middleware approach I usually take is creating a base class with the `LoginRequiredMixin` to ensure that all views are using it. In your own unit test cases you can even check if the correct base class is used to ensure the views are secured.

Comment: another thing that I don't understand is that the test which is failing belongs to the UserAPI tests and the middleware I wrote gets the `LOGIN_URL = '/admin'` so I am having a hard time understanding how this middleware is affecting the `/api/` endpoints since they are disconnected

Answer (score -1):

Something like:

```py
class Redirect401Response(HttpResponseRedirect):
   status_code = 401


def process_request(request):
    ...
    return Redirect401Response(resolve_url(f"{settings.LOGIN_URL}?next=/{path}"))
```

?